# How to echo the information depending on what day it is? PHP

Tags: php, date

I am very new to php and I am trying to get out the info on one particular day. So if it is monday I will echo "its monday" and I have started with a code below. I have read that you get the day by the number 0-6 if iam not misstaken: 1 = monday and 6 = saturday.

```
<?php
$day = strftime ('%A', time ());
if ($day == ("1")  )
{
echo "Its monday";
}

else if ($day == ("6"))
{
echo "Its saturday";
}
else
{
echo "Not saturday or monday";
}

?>
```

UPDATED:

```
  <?php
$day = strftime ('%A', time ());
if ($day == ("1")  )
{
echo "It's " . date('l');
}

else if ($day == ("6"))
{
echo "It's " . date('l');
}
else
{
echo "It's " . date('l');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the manual on http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

> *%A    A full textual representation of the day    Sunday through Saturday*

You're checking for an integer rather than a string using `%A`.

If you want to use numbers for representation, use `%e`

> *%e    Day of the month, with a space preceding single digits. Not implemented as described on Windows. See below for more information.    1 to 31*

```
$day = strftime ('%e', time ());
if ($day == ("7")  )
{
echo "Its monday";
}

else if ($day == ("6"))
{
echo "Its saturday";
}
else
{
echo "Not saturday or monday";
}
```

Otherwise, use `%A` and check for a string and use a string `("Monday")`:

```
$day = strftime ('%A', time ());
if ($day == ("Monday")  )
{
echo "Its monday";
}

else if ($day == ("Saturday"))
{
echo "Its saturday";
}
else
{
echo "Not saturday or monday";
}
```

---

**Foonotes:**

Be careful though, `Monday` and `monday` are not treated the same and they are case-sensitive. Same thing goes for every other days of the week if you are going to use strings.

Comment: $day = strftime ('%A', time ());
if ($day == ("Monday")  )
{
echo "Its monday";
}

else if ($day == (”Saturday"))
{
echo "Its saturday";
}
else
{
echo "Not saturday or monday";
}

So this works then?

Comment: @William.John Yes it does. I've tested it against "today's" day. So it will work for you tomorrow being Monday. But be careful, `monday` and `Monday` are not the same and they are case-sensitive. etc.

Comment: @William.John You're very much welcome, *cheers* and welcome to Stack ;-)

Comment: @datelligence It's by personal preference really. I myself particularly like using a ternary operator. Using switch/case has its conveniences for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for the `date()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

In your example, you could output the current day like this:

```
print "It's " . date('l');
```

(that's a lowercase "L" in the call to `date()`)

Comment: Kind of. If you're just trying to output "It's <the day name>" you don't actually need the if/else if/else blocks, you can just use the single line of code above and it will always output the current day name (based on the server time).

Answer (score 0):

some thing like this :

```
  $t=date('d-m-Y');
echo date("D",strtotime($t));
```

Comment: But how can I then write a appropiate text to that certain day?

Comment: you can use jddayofweek function of php as above .

Answer (score 0):

`$day = strftime ('%A', time ());` returns a the day as a String e.g. 'Sunday'
So if you really want to use if conditions, presumably to print out more than simply the date, you can do the following:

```
  <?php
$day = strftime ('%A', time ());
if ($day == ("Monday")  )
{
echo "It's " . date('l');
  //etc ...
}

else if ($day == ("Sunday"))
{
echo "It's " . date('l');
   //etc ...
}
else
{
  echo "It's " . date('l');
  //etc ...
}

?>
```